# VIM Blockwise Insert

Tags: ruby, vim

I would like to insert a hash at the beginning of a selected block of text in VIM (ruby comment). I selected the lines in Visual Mode, but how do I perform the same operation to all lines?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two primary options:

- Select in block visual mode (ctrl-v), then use `I` to insert the same thing along the left side of the entire block. Similarly `A` appends; see [blockwise operators](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#blockwise-operators).
- Select the lines in normal visual (v) or visual line (V) mode, then run the same command on all of them, for example `s/^/# /` or `normal I#`. Typing `:` while you have a visual selection automatically uses the visual selection as the line range (denoted by `'<,'>`).

Comment: Block visual mode did not work for me, but normal did. In block visual, I selected the first char of every line, and it deleted all of them, not putting what I wanted in. 

The second worked though, thank you!

Comment: @tesmar: I use that all the time; I know it works - you must've done some little thing wrong. `ctrl-v`, get the selection you want (first char is fine, like you did), `I# <Esc>`.

Comment: You are right, it worked once I realized I had to press ctrl + v. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm on Redhat/Centos vim `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jul  7 2012 08:03:48)` and neither `I` nor `A` works on visual blocks

Comment: @gerrytan Well, the docs do say "{not available when compiled without the |+visualextra| feature}" - the full output of vim --version will tell you whether or not it was built with the feature. But I'm pretty sure it was there well before 2012 - I remember using this on CentOS 5, and it's documented as being included in the normal compiles. Do you have multiple packaged versions of vim? You aren't using vim-tiny, are you?

Comment: The default vim installed with Ubuntu 14.04 (installed as `vi`) does not include `visualextra`, so block insert won't work there. `sudo apt-get install vim` brings in a more full-featured version, on which `visualextra` is activated

Answer (score 5):

While in visual mode do the

```
:'<,'>s/^/#
```

actually, `'<,'>` will be inserted automatically when you hit `:`.

Answer (score 2):

You better use this.

COMMAND MODE with set number to see lines

> :10,50s/^/#/g

First number before comma is the start line and second number after comma is the end line. Both are included.

Comment: This isn't quite how you deal with a visual selection.

Comment: @Jefromi, yes, but it is faster in the execution of the desired result.

Comment: Sure, if you already know the line numbers. What if the fastest way to specify the selection `nVn`, or `V}}}`? Why force yourself to look up line numbers? Just use `nVn:s/.../.../`.

Answer (score 0):

Another question might have copied this question, so came here from How to Insert in Visual Block Mode.

Highly recommend that people take a look at this cheat sheet: http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

As people do more research into VIM people will see a lot of %s/^/# with the % sign in front and by replacing the % sign with what pops up in Visual Block Mode with :'<,'> the symbols that pop up you are able to do insert, etc.

```
:'<,'>s/^/# (applied on selected lines only)

:%s/^/# (applied globally)
```

(sharing my two cents after researching how to add a hrefs' to different lines).