# Vim: How to insert in visual block mode?

Tags: vim

How can you insert when you are in visual block mode (by pressing ctrl-V) in Vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM Blockwise Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874952/vim-blockwise-insert)

Answer (score 349, accepted):

**Try this**

After selecting a block of text, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or capital <kbd>I</kbd>.

Lowercase <kbd>i</kbd> will not work.

Then type the things you want and finally to apply it to all lines, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice.

**If this doesn't work...**

Check if you have `+visualextra` enabled in your version of Vim.

You can do this by typing in `:ver` and scrolling through the list of features. (You might want to copy and paste it into a buffer and do incremental search because the format is odd.)

Enabling it is outside the scope of this question but I'm sure you can find it somewhere.

Comment: You also have to press escape to exit insert mode before the text will be duplicated.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen this not work? I have a non-modified vim setup on CentOS. I press ctrl+v, press j a few times, and I see the cursor highlight the first character of a few lines. I press shift+i. The cursor is moved to the first character of the first line, but I'm back to normal mode. I know this because if I press "a", it moves the character to the right, and it says "-- INSERT --". If I type a few characters and press escape, it's not applied to the other lines.

Comment: @TylerCollier I'm experiencing the problem on Ubuntu 14.04 on digitalocean.  Please comment if you've found a solution.

Comment: @ZacharyBurt Sorry, no solution.

Comment: @TylerCollier I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04.5. For my particular use case I was able to use "c" after opening the visual block per Nishant's answer below.

Comment: @sixty4bit I've never had this issue on Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I can't try your answer on the CentOS box I originally mentioned. I don't have access to any CentOS machines any more.

Comment: @ZacharyBurt The default vim installed with Ubuntu 14.04 (installed as `vi`) does not include the `visualextra` feature, so block insert won't work there. `sudo apt-get install vim` brings in a more full-featured version, on which `visualextra` is activated. @TylerCollier This may be the same issue on your CentOS install too: check the output of `vim --version` to see the full list of activated features.

Comment: @GabrielGrant Unfortunately, it says +visualextra for me.  Is there a dotfile configuration I have to make to activate it?

Comment: @ZacharyBurt hmm, strange. Did you already manually install vim? Once I did, visual block insert worked immediately without any dotfile change.

Comment: @Honghe.Wu because `i` and `a` are used to extends the selection to text objects, read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32001306/2123306) to this question or type `:help visual-operators`.

Comment: @Zachary Burt,Just as Broandon Joyce sayed,  Maybe you fogot to press the ESC after you insert chars to the first selected row, this action take effects. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim

Comment: ... and also don't forget `r` (great for ascii art)

Comment: @TylerCollier I also encountered this question, and I post a question here and get the answer, check the http://stackoverflow.com/q/41670493/6521116

Comment: If any poor souls like me are wondering why this concept doesn't work when you want to just delete stuff, well that's because you can just block select and hit the delete key. Or else see [Nishan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24550148/327074) and use the 'c' key which deletes and puts you in insert mode, then you can either add in new text or just hit escape and you're done

Comment: I'm on a mac and this did not work.  What did work for me was this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43076392/61624 . In summary, press escape **twice** after you edit.

Comment: Double escape does not propagate changes to other lines, esc double j does.

Comment: What is the reason for hitting escape twice instead of once? Seems to be working for me with just once.

Comment: @TylerCollier you have to press <esc> twice for the changes to be applied to all the lines

Comment: Link to exact time in vim visual editing video tutorial showing this: https://youtu.be/PHskKxkM-nA?t=76

Answer (score 77):

1. press ctrl and v   // start select
2. press shift and i  // then type in any text
3. press esc esc      // press esc **twice**

Comment: After pressing `ctrl + v`, you can press `j` to quickly select line(s) below the current position, or press `k` to quickly select line(s) above the current position. You can also use the `shift` key with the `up` or `down` errors to do the selection.

Comment: Of all the answers, this is the only one that worked for me.  I'm on a mac using the brew install

Comment: I've been complaining for years that I couldn't easily **i**nsert (like **c**hange) in block select. So it's with a capital `i`, I'm amazed. I've been using `:normal iINPUT<CR>` to input at the beginning of lines. Thanks a bunch for this!

Comment: I don't think you need to press esc twice. If you press anything after esc, it would automatically update the text. If not, it will do it in like half a second or so.

Answer (score 38):

You  might also have a use case where you want to delete a block of text and replace it .

Like this

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

You can visual block select before "W" and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> - Type "Cool" - Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then delete "World" by visual block selection .

Alternatively, the cooler way to do it is to **just visual block** select "World" in both lines. Type <kbd>c</kbd> for `change`. Now you are in the `insert` mode. Insert the stuff you want and hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Both gets reflected with lesser keystrokes.

```
Hello Cool 
Hello Cool
```

Comment: the final step is helpful for me,  you must hit `ESC` then all the marked line will show the char which you type in.

Comment: great stuff, it helps a lot

Comment: Good example. Any idea how to delete columns? I'm trying to remove some inconsistent indentation but I'm not convinced it can be done to remove columns, only add.

Answer (score 25):

if you want to add new text before or after the selected colum:

- press ctrl+v
- select columns
- press shift+i
- write your text
- press esc
- press "jj"

Comment: Tank you, `jj` to propagate the changes to all lines below was the last bit I was missing!

Comment: `jj` is a killer!

Comment: Could someone please explain `jj`? I could not manage to find anything about it and seems unnecessary to me. 

Comment: jj is useful to propagate your change to all other lines...if in your case it is not needed, maybe it could be because something has been changed in newer versions of VIM

Comment: Yeah my version didn't need it either but good to know just in case.

Comment: My version does not need jj either. You can just write and it will appear in all lines. Makes also sense that this was changed since that should be the normal use case for using `Visual Block` mode.

Answer (score 7):

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Apr 03 2023 07:45:49)

```
CTRL + q  - ENTER VISUAL MODE
j or k    - SELECT LINES BELOW OR ABOVE
SHIFT + i - ADD CONTENT TO THE FIRST LINE
ESC       - EXIT INSERT MODE
j         - PROPAGATE CHANGES TO THE OTHER LINES
```